# Как добавить программу в автозагрузку Windows используя C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-7

Можно ли добавить программу в автозагрузку с помощью C/C++? (без WinAPI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите линк в `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Нужно только ярлык или саму exe?

Comment: Ярлык, разумеется.